# get cart name based on quote id

Tags: magento

If there are multiple products ordered by customers, how to get the product name (eg. : `[name] => LG LED46 TV`)  based on the quote id in `magento`.
I have used the following:

```
$quotecollection= Mage::getModel('sales/quote')->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter("quote_id", $order->getQuoteId())->getFirstItem();
```

Answer (score 0):

Below is the code which uses the customer id of a logged in customer to extract the item

```
$customerQuote = Mage::getModel('sales/quote') 
                        ->setStoreId(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId())
                        ->loadByCustomer(Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomerId()
                    ); 
    if ($customerQuote->getId()) 
    { 

        foreach ($customerQuote->getAllItems() as $item) 
        { 
        //this is your product name
        $product_name = $item['name'];
        }
    }
```

Dump the value of **$item**  to get other attributes of the product if required.

Hope this will help.

Comment: Im using this for the custom email template. Other values i have used it as follows. can u please suggest how to use the same for my requirement, for multiple products.  Below is the code used for other values in Observer.php    $vars['selleraddress'] = $customer->getCompany_address();
      $vars['currency'] = $order->getOrder_currency_code();
      $vars['podate'] = $order->getCreated_at();
      $vars['suppierno'] = $customer->getEntity_id();
      $vars['orderno'] =$order->getIncrementId();
      $vars['suborderno'] = 'ActiveCodeline';
      $vars['povalidtilldate'] = 'ActiveCodeline';

Comment: Have you checked this. Think this may be helpful to you.http://www.gemgento.com/blog/customizing-magento-order-emails

Comment: $quotecollection = Mage::getModel("sales/quote_item")->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('quote_id',$order->getQuote_id());;
                                       $quote = $quotecollection->getData();.   how to extract only required information from the entire quote information. I ned to display them in the email template

Comment: foreach($quoteCollection as $item){
 $name = $item['name'];
}
I am just showing an example here, you can use foreach to get each item and then get the required info. Dump $item->getData() to get for info about the item

Comment: thanks for ur help. for extracting the price from the quote , im using the following : $price=Mage::getModel("sales/quote_item")->getCollection()->   addFieldToFilter('price',$order->getPrice());
                                 Mage:: log($order->getBase_price(),null,'price.log');                Im getting blank in the log file please help

Comment: I think you can also get the price from the code that i have given above. You just need to do $price = $item['price']; inside the foreach loop. to get the price of the item.

Comment: Ya i have got that, but i want to store the extracted value in the variable . Other variables i m using like: $vars['orderno'] =$order->getIncrementId();       Same way, i have to extract 'name' and store, but i want to store multiple product names (im using custom order email template)